# GIT não faz o push

Tags: git, bitbucket

Pessoal não sei oque ocorre com meu git, já desinstalei e instalei e nada!
sempre que vou fazer um push ocorre o seguinte...

```
$ git clone https://[...]/projeto.git
$ git checkout -b "#CASA"
$ git add <meus_arquivos>
$ git commit -m "Descrição"
$ git push origin #CASA
fatal: The current branch #CASA has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin #CASA
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que o nome do seu branch remoto possui uma hash (`#`) no começo. No terminal, isso é interpretado como um comentário.

Tente colocar aspas simples (`'`) ao redor do nome do branch:

```
git push origin '#CASA'
```

Comment: Deu certo! tu é o cara @RodrigoRigotti